# Populating after saving

Tags: node.js, json, web-services, express, mongoose

I have this piece of code:

```
message.save().then(message => {
    let result = {
        ok: true,
        message
    }
    res.send(result);
})
```

Which gives this json:

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "message": {
        "_id": "5c5fe65236bcc31eb0a3db46",
        "from": "5c5f1f1c4042b431d4611127",
        "to": "5c5f201b4042b431d4611128",
        "message": "Con imagen",
        "image": "img/1549788754143.jpg",
        "sent": "2019-02-10T08:52:34.144Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
}
```

I want to populate the from field, which is the best way to do it?
I've only used populate after .find(), and I can't find any way to do it.

.save() doesn't allow you to use .populate()

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
message.save().then(savedMessage => {
            Message.findById(savedMessage._id).populate('from').then(data => {
                let result = {
                    ok: true,
                    data
                }
                res.send(result);
            })
        })
```

.save() doesn't have the method .populate() so this trick makes it possible to return a populated field in a web service, which is pretty useful.

The json that this web service returns is now like this:

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "data": {
        "_id": "5c60791c834b900bf0383440",
        "from": {
            "_id": "5c5f1f1c4042b431d4611127",
            "name": "admin",
            "password": "03ac674216f3e15c761ee1a5e255f067953623c8b388b4459e13f978d7c846f4",
            "image": "img/1549737756964.jpg",
            "__v": 0
        },
        "to": "5c5f201b4042b431d4611128",
        "message": "Con imagen",
        "image": "img/1549826332017.jpg",
        "sent": "2019-02-10T19:18:52.018Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
}
```